# Multiple messageListener with Spring and RabbitMQ and DirectMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

Following code given:

```
    DirectMessageListenerContainer container = new DirectMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queues);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
```

How can I have one listenerAdapter PER queue? Which means multiple adapters for multithreading. In case of setting a breakpoint at one listener, the other queues should continue to work.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems i have to use setChannelAwareMessageListener()